# use libcap but: undefined reference

Tags: kotlin-native

#cat libCap.def

```
headers = sys/capability.h
headerFilter = sys/*

compilerOpts.linux = -I/usr/include
linkerOpts.linux = -L/usr/lib -lcap
```

when i run `runDebugExecutableNative --stacktrace`  , it output that:

e: /home/adlyq/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld.gold invocation reported errors

The /home/adlyq/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld.gold command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
/usr/lib/libcap.so: error: undefined reference to '__isoc23_strtoul', version 'GLIBC_2.38'
/usr/lib/libcap.so: error: undefined reference to 'lstat64', version 'GLIBC_2.33'
/usr/lib/libcap.so: error: undefined reference to 'fstat64', version 'GLIBC_2.33'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':linkDebugExecutableNative'.

> Compilation finished with errors

how can i fix it